# Pthread: Multiple File Access

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

I have two threads that will be accessing multiples files. These two threads might try to access the same file at the same time. How can I guarantee exclusive access to a file in this scenario using pthread functions and structs in C, knowing that there will be a very large number of files that these two threads will be accessing? I know I can create a big number of mutexes, but that doesn't seem like the way to go since there is a limit to that number.

Comment: Maintain a lock per file and use it when any thread wants to access a file.

Comment: Why would the threads be at risk of accessing the same file at the same time?  Can you prevent that from being a possibility?  Do the threads close the files?  What's a 'very large number of files'?  Tens, hundreds, thousands, more?  Where does the list of files come from?

Comment: 1. They'd be at risk of accessing the same file because they'll both be doing write and read operations on them.
2. That I cannot.
3. Threads neither open nor close the files, the access is done through a library.
4. A large number of files is a number around the thousands or tens of thousands.
5. The list of file is predetermined, I know it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Have each thread place an advisory write-lock the file that's it's about to access using,  for example,  flock().

Comment: I can't use flock() nor flockfile() because I'm not handling the opening and closing of the file, those things are handled by a library, hence why I specifically asked for a solution using pthread material.

I've thought about using a pool of mutexes and hashing the name of the files to match a specific mutex in that pool. Would that be a good idea? Since both threads will be able to read and write to the files, should I use read-write locks instead of mutexes?

Comment: Using whatever unique, file-specific information you have to access a file-specific read-write lock should work.